# .jar file not getting launched

Tags: java, jar, corretto

I've used Amazon corretto and Java's jre(javaw.exe) to try running my jar file. The task manager says that 'Java Platform SE Binary' is running but no dialogue box(or display) of the jar program is shown on my laptop.
I even tried opening it through command prompt or through a bat file, all in vain.
Any and all help would be deeply appreciated! Thanks! [Task Manager snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRG3a.jpg)

Comment: Is your program supposed to open a window? Can you add the relevant parts of the code to the question

Comment: I'm trying to open the "DSC_MGMT_UTILITY.jar" file that enables us to generate a digital signature.

Answer (score 1):

A java app does.. what the java app does.

Which may well involve no GUI whatsoever. You won't notice anything whatsoever in your windows environment if the java app you're trying to start doesn't actively involve any GUI elements from e.g. the `javax.swing` package.

Try using `java.exe` - `javaw.exe` does not show any console input or output, whereas `java.exe` does. If it's a console app (that reads and prints text from the command line), it would simply appear to be doing nothing if you try to launch it with `javaw.exe`.

For example, this app:

```
// Save this as 'Example.java'
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

then open a 'dos box' (run `cmd.exe`), navigate to the proper directory, and run:

```
javac Example.java
javaw Example
```

does nothing. You witness precisely what you are witnessing (or possibly you can't witness it as the app closes too fast. But you certainly won't see any windows or any text). Then run:

```
java Example
```

and you'll see: `Hello, World!` and then the app exits.

If 'the command line' is gobbledygook to you, well, if you want to program, you're going to have to know how it works, but, fortunately, there are plenty of tutorials around :)